# Java REST GET method with different return types

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to implement a REST method GET in a Spring Boot application which delivers a file being of different types.

For example it could return a PDF document, a JPEG image, a TIF image, etc., in fact what ever there is.

How to do this?
Shall I specify the return type as Object:

```
@GetMapping("/document")
public Object getDocument() { 
   file = ... logic to retrieve a specific file (PDF, JPEG, TIF, ...)
   return file;
}
```

And what has the Client side to do with the returned value, to make the right file type out of it?

Cheers

Comment: For the client side, you could return the type of object in the header of the response. This way they know how to parse it or where to save it

Comment: This is what the MIME type header is for.  Let the client decide what format they'd like to receive it in.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new class to specify response. It should be something like:

```
public class Response{
    public String type;
    public Byte[] fileContent
    ... getter/setter/constructor etc
}
```

This idea should be fine for small files (images or pdf). With large files it becomes more complicated

Comment: Thanks, this idea came later also in my mind. The Client has to evaluate the Response. So the return type of the GET method would then be simply Response?

Comment: I think response type json fits here the best. One more thing you could try in your app is to return link to image, or pdf, instead of passing image file content in response. Browser will call the back end image using link you provided in response. Any way I would recommend to search web "spring boot rest controller". There a lot of more detailed examples.

Answer (score 0):

By Spring I think you meant spring-mvc.
you can do something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void getImageSling(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException {

    //read the file in byte[]
    //evaluate content type you want to set
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.getOutputStream().write(byteStream.getByteStream());
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure if Sping MVC, it is definitely a Spring Boot application. I see the REST controller, I see different methods (GET; POST, ...), now I want to implement such a GET. I thought usually the method uses "return ...", but in this context within a REST controller using HttpServletResponse with your suggestion also works? Or is this only possible if it is a Spring MVC?

Comment: spring boot does not handle rest. Spring MVC handles the rest(Get/put/post). So you can use this answer without any worry, try it out.

Comment: The technology behind it is still Servlet (as of HttpServletResponse)? Didn't expect this in a Spring application. I thought Servlet is an old technology used back then with JSP.

Comment: `Spring MVC is essentially a higher level abstraction built on top of Java Servlets centered around the Model View Controller design pattern. This pattern promotes separation of concerns when building your web application.`

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of delivering different view representations for different client requests there is notion of view resolvers in Spring MVC.

Particularly you need to configure `ContentNegotiationViewResolver` and friends according to your supported document extension types.

You can find more [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc)